# Unity Update Method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to have a value that is constantly being updated, eg. the current time (that the program has run) and use it in a function? basically I need the time to constantly update in my function (current time is taken from my update function)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current time using [Time.time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html)

Comment: It doesn't run continously in a function other than the update function.

Comment: What do you mean by 'run continuously in a function'? What exactly are you trying to make?